# How to use getDerivedStateFromProps along with redux in react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am having a redux state like question with array of objects which are rendering checkboxes using map function in jsx:

```
const datafromredux = [
    {
      id:1,
      option1 : false,
    },
    {
      id:2,
      option2 : true,
    },
    {
      id:3,
      option3 : true,
    },
    {
      id:4,
      option4 : false,
    },
    {
      id:5,
      option5 : false,
    }]

const options = [
    {
      id:1,
      option1 : false,
    },
    {
      id:2,
      option2 : false,
    },
    {
      id:3,
      option3 : false,
    },
    {
      id:4,
      option4 : false,
    },
    {
      id:5,
      option5 : false,
    }]
```

Initially `datafromredux={}` imagine in the UI options was rendering the 5 checkboxes when the clicks the respective option is updated finally when the user clicks on submit it was saving to redux store this was made persistent using session storage when the user refresh the page the data which was stored in redux should be taken instead from the component level thing using `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

How can I achieve it using hooks? I tried using:

```
const [checkboxs, setCheckboxes] = useState(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect")
        if(datafromredux){
          setCheckboxes(datafromredux)
        }
        else{
          setCheckboxes(excludedGasesBase)
        }
      }, [gases])
```

and rendering the checkboxes using

```
{checkboxs.map((data) => {
                  return(
                <div  key={data.id}>
                  <input type="checkbox" onChange={handleCheckboxes} name={data.name} value={data.id} id={data.name} checked={data.checked}/>
                  <labelhtmlFor={data.name}></label>
                </div>
                )})}
```

Comment: If user refresh the page the store will be reset, you wont get any data.

Comment: no on click of submit it was storing in redux and storing to session storage when user refresh also redux  will be getting from session storage and component is getting from redux

Comment: so are you facing issue to restore from session storage to redux on page refresh?

Comment: no i am getting the redux data my problem is when user visiting the page first the checkboxes should render using options(component state/initial state) and when the user fill the check boxes clicks submit then refresh the page the data should be taken from redux state ie datafromredux

Comment: i am facing issue with how to toggle between these 2

Comment: ok, You do not need `useState` or `useEffect`, just use `useSelector`. So initially it will be null as nothing in redux store, but when user will set it `useSelector` will return the state to the variable.

Comment: ha okay can you give some idea to toggle b/w those 2

Comment: I have created this code sandbox, please check https://codesandbox.io/s/reactredux-forked-80d66